# React/TypeScript Dynamic Switch Statement using Dependency Injection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dependency-injection, websocket

I am currently working on a Websocket communication bus on React using typescript. Currently, trying to refactor this code:

```
public onClientMessage(msg: IMessage) {
  switch (msg.type) {
    case "init": {
      this.handleInit(msg);
      break;
    }
    case "authorize": {
      this.handleAuthorize(msg);
      break;
    }
    case "render": {
      this.handleRender(msg as IRenderMessage);
      break;
    }
    default: {
      console.warn("Unsupported type. Type: ", msg.type);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

So that it can be abstracted out and other classes can add new message type and function call to this method. 
I was looking into Dependency Injection (more or less http://inversify.io/). However, i feel it might be an overkill for a simple task.

Is there something else you guys can suggest? I also thought about something like this:

```
private map = new Map<Message, (msg) => void>([
  [Message.Init, this.handleInit(msg)],
  [Message.Authorize, this. handleAuthorize(msg)],
  [Message.Render, this. handleRender(msg)] ...
]);

onClientMessage(msgType: Message, msg: IMessage) {
  if (this.map.has(msgType)) {
    this.map.get(msgType)();
  }
}
```

And basically append to the map.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with websockets in general so maybe someone else can provide a better answer but I think you are over thinking it.

I don't really see the point in using dependency injection or classes here when simple functions will do

Without more code or clarifying I don't see what's wrong with either code samples here.

Either way you have to have some type of conditional or key/value map.

Comment: I agree with @MartinDawson. The described use case reminds me Redux Thunk a bit. You might take inspiration from there.

Comment: Yeah thats what i was thinking. I might be overthinking this too much. Thanks guys

Comment: I actually really like the Map approach. I've done something similar and it's worked out really nice.

Comment: I would keep the switch statement but use string and typeof for the type property to type your messages, so that typescript can infer the message type in the switch statement (so no more casting such as "msg as IRenderMessage").
You can check the redux documentation for a complete example: https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-actions--action-creators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem Definition

You have a socket receiving messages. You want to dynamically add handlers that are executed depending on the type of the message, but you do not know upfront what handlers exist, but want to add them dynamically. Actually, they should add themselves.

So basically, you need some **Manager** that exposes an API to *register* or *remove* **handlers** and on messages **triggers** the right handlers.

**A word on Dependency Injection**

Dependency Injection solves a different problem. Using inversion of control it solves the problem of not knowing the *implementation* or instance of a specific service or API while *knowing upfront* what API is *needed* - so it **depends** on it. In general, letting the context decide for a specific implementation or instance to provide the dependency helps isolating, meshups and especially reasoning about the unit (e.g. for unit testing). There is more to say about dependency injection, but it should already be clear, that it is not suited to solve the problem defintion on its on (but it will be helpful as stated later).

## Solution Approach

**Building a Manager** is easy and your Map is the right approach. Basically, you need some kind of *mapping* to know which handler to call for an incoming message. You cold now decide if you allow a *single* handler per type or *multiple*. You currently allow a single handler per type in the Map. If you want to support multiple you keep the key (*message type*) and the value of the map would become a list of handlers.

**The Manager API** To let modules **register** and **remove** themselves, I would suggest to apply an observer (or listener) pattern. Here you could also decide if your manager actually takes control of who to call or if the listeners / observers are called on every message and they themselve decide if they want to react on the message. The latter is common to redux, but for your usecase a manager in control seems a good choice. You also want to embed the `onClientMessage` in the manager (this is often called *emit* in terms of events that are emitted to the listeners).

From your current Map approach you just need to encapsulate that map in a class that provides registering and removing listeners:

```
const createMessageHandlerManager = () => {
  // message-type => listener
  const listeners = {};
  return {
    addListener: (key, listener) => {
      if (listeners[key]) {
        throw new Error(`Listener already present for key '${key}'`);
      }
      listeners[key] = listener;
    },
    removeListener: (key) => {
      if (!key || !listeners[key])) {
        return;
      }
      delete listeners[key];
    },
    onClientMessage: (msgType: Message, msg: IMessage) => {
      const handler = listeners[msgType];
      if (handler) {
        handler(msg);
      }
    },
  };
};
```

**Providing** the manager is the next task.  Using `const manager = createMessageHandlerManager()` it is created, but who should create it? How do your modules get to know the manager? Either you have some kind of global state that all your modules can refer to, so they can register themselves (or their event handlers) to the manager. OR during their construction they require a reference to the manager (making it *dependency **injection***). The decision is yours and depends on the context where you want to apply such pattern. If, for example, you want properly test your modules, I would suggest that dependency injection is a good idea, because it is very easy to mock the manager and isolate the unit under test.

A module (e.g. a component) then basically could register with the manager on mount and unregister on unmount:

```
const ModuleA = ({ messageHandlerManager }) => {
  const handleInit = useCallback(msg => console.log(msg), []);
  const handleAuthorize = useCallback(msg => console.log(msg), []);
  useEffect(() => {
    messageHandlerManager.addListener(Message.Init, handleInit);
    messageHandlerManager.addListener(Message.Authorize, handleAuthorize);
    return () => {
      messageHandlerManager.removeListener(Message.Init, handleInit);
      messageHandlerManager.removeListener(Message.Authorize, handleAuthorize);
    };
  }, []);

  // ... render ...
};
```

## Summary

To get rid of the `switch` in order to make it dynamic you already have a good approach. Just *encapsulate* the map and the `onClientMessage` together with *register/remove* API in a **manager**. Next, decide who is reponsible for creating and providing the manager to the modules and you are good to go!

Comment: Oh and I had another thought when first reading your question that I forgot to put in the answer: dependency injection is easy as a concept and you are using it already all over the place. A framework is sometimes needed because it might get very hard to create the dependency graph (ie creating and setting all dependencies correctly - you may have experienced giving props to child components so much that it becomes a pain and you rather try providing information somehow differently (Redux, Context Api etc) . But in your case it is straight forward.